# Get starting and ending coordinates for mouseDragged event

Tags: objective-c

I am making an application to keep track of which keys were pressed and where the user clicked on the screen, as well as when and where they drag the mouse.  I've gotten the first two implemented, but I'm not sure how to proceed with getting the starting and ending coordinates for a single mouse drag.

This is what I have so far:

```
dragWatcher = [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSLeftMouseDraggedMask handler:^(NSEvent *event) {
      NSLog(@"----------------------\n");
      NSLog(@"dX: %.2lf dY:%.2lf", [event deltaX], [event deltaY]);
      NSLog(@"----------------------\n");
}];
```

Why is it that when I drag a window (without stopping), there are multiple log lines?  I would have expected that as long as I don't release the mouse button, it should count as the same action.  TIA!

Edit:  sample of the NSLog...

```
2014-05-08 16:12:11.821 Recorder[17504:303] dX: 1.00 dY:0.00
2014-05-08 16:12:11.822 Recorder[17504:303] ----------------------
2014-05-08 16:12:11.838 Recorder[17504:303] ----------------------
2014-05-08 16:12:11.838 Recorder[17504:303] dX: 6.00 dY:-4.00
2014-05-08 16:12:11.838 Recorder[17504:303] ----------------------
2014-05-08 16:12:11.854 Recorder[17504:303] ----------------------
2014-05-08 16:12:11.854 Recorder[17504:303] dX: 3.00 dY:-4.00
2014-05-08 16:12:11.854 Recorder[17504:303] ----------------------
2014-05-08 16:12:11.871 Recorder[17504:303] ----------------------
2014-05-08 16:12:11.871 Recorder[17504:303] dX: 21.00 dY:-15.00
2014-05-08 16:12:11.871 Recorder[17504:303] ----------------------
```

Comment: What NSLog are you getting right now?

Comment: why do you think there would only be one dragged event?

Comment: Dragging is a continuous gesture, so you get calls every time the mouse moves. You can use the NSLeftMouseDown and NSLeftMouseUp to get calls when those events happen.

Comment: Hm, but how would I differentiate between a drag and a click, then?

Comment: I think you'll have to grab pairs of mouseDowns and mouseUps and look at their location property, and call it a drag if the locations are different by more than some threshold. You could also get the initial position from the first call to mouseDragged.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand what an `NSLeftMouseDragged` event is. It is exactly analogous to an `NSMouseMoved` event, except that the left/primary mouse button is held down. It does not indicate the totality of a drag from mouse-down until mouse-up.

Apps need to get continuous updates on the mouse position during a drag so they can respond. For example, when you click in a push button, it highlights while the cursor is inside. If you move the cursor out of the button, it unhighlights. If you move it back in, it highlights again. By your interpretation of `NSLeftMouseDragged`, the app would not have received additional events until the button was released and the drag ended.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now.  I think I'm going to try to pursue @rdelmar 's suggestion.